# Gcloud Export to Google Storage from Cloud SQL instance as .sql file

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I wanted to export DB in .sql format from Cloud SQL before executing SQL queries on that DB.
I wanted to do this from Jenkins pipeline, hence I used following Gcloud export command to perform this task.
**Command Syntax:**
gcloud sql export sql dbinstancename gs://storagename/foldername/filename.sql --database=databasename

Using this same command from cloud shell I'm able to achieve the goal.
While doing from cloud shell it prompts for authorization, post authorization the export is happening successfully.

When I do from Jenkins pipeline, I'm getting following error.
**Error:** ERROR: (gcloud.sql.export.sql) HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request.

**Troubleshooting steps performed:**

- Verified the SA(Service Account), it is part of "Cloud SQL Admin" and "Storage Admin" roles.
- Tried this option prior to export command but no luck "gcloud auth application-default login"
- Tied this command prior to export command but no luck  "gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser"

Kindly let me know if further details required, and suggest me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

`ERROR: (gcloud.sql.export.sql) HTTPError 403: The client is not authorized to make this request.`

**Solution:**

In such case please connect to a worker pod in GKE and run the commands from there. Worker will have correct permission to talk to the SQL instance.

In case if you still facing the same issue after trying this solution means kindly let me know.

Comment: I'm not using GKE, have Compute Engine.

Comment: Sorry for Misunderstanding @Mani

Answer (score 0):

Load the service account key file in the GCLOUD cli with this command

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/to/key.json
```

Comment: I tried this option, I got this message "activated service account credentials for: service-account". However I received the same 403 error.

Comment: Adding to that, My Jenkins server is in Project1, Cloud SQL instance is in Project2, which service account I need to use for the activation. 
I tried with "gcloud auth list" command in the pipeline to find the SA, it was listing Project1 SA. Hence, I used Project1 SA for the activation, but it didnt help.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline steps (service account activation then gcloud command line usage)?

Comment: I used following comments:

gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/filepath/keyfile.json  (used Project1 SA)

gcloud sql export sql dbinstancename gs://storagename/foldername/filename.sql --database=databasename

Please let me know if further details needed @guillaume blaquiere .

Comment: Does the Project1 SA have "Cloud SQL Admin" and "Storage Admin" roles in **the project2**?

Comment: Yes, it has the mentioned roles in Project 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the service account running the SQL instance permissions to access the bucket (in the bucket permissions section). The SQL instance service account is the one that writes to the bucket, not the user's service account.

Answer (score 0):

CloudSQL export is not performed by the Service Account used on Jenkins but by a special dedicated Service Account of your CloudSQL database.

1. Go to your Cloud SQL instance and copy the service account of the CloudSQL instance (Cloud SQL->{instance name}->OVERVIEW->Service account). Something like: `<service_account_id>@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
2. Assign the necessary role to the CloudSQL service account so it can create objects in the Cloud Storage Bucket.